# Combine values from 2 different dictionaries in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, flask, iterator, jinja2

I have 2 dicts for example

```
dict1 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3 }
dict2 = { 'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c':7, 'd':8, 'e':9}
```

The dicts can vary , sometimes dict1 can be longer than dict2.
These dicts are passed to html page using flask.
The jinja code is as follows

```
{% for key, value in dict1.items() %}
   <tr>
     <th>{{key}}</th>
     <td>{{value}}</td>
     <td>{{dict2.get(key,'0')}}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The output is as follows for the above dicts

```
a   1   5
b   2   6
c   3   7
```

How can I get the following output

```
a   1   5
b   2   6
c   3   7
d   0   8
e   0   9
```

And vice versa if dict1 is longer than dict2 .
Can I achieve it using jinja or it should be computed in python and rendered with the final result. If it has to be computed in python how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Get all unique keys

```
dict1 = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3 }
dict2 = { 'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c':7, 'd':8, 'e':9}

keys = list(set((list(dict1.keys()) + list(dict2.keys()))))
keys.sort()
```

Iterate over the keys and get the values

```
{% for key in keys %}
   <tr>
     <th>{{key}}</th>
     <td>{{dict1.get(key, 0)}}</td>
     <td>{{dict2.get(key, 0)}}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```